# NodeJS HTTPResponse from MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, http

i have a NODEJS server which is waiting for HTTPREQUESTS. Based on the request it gets some data from the MongoDB and send it back as a Response. JavaScript is a synchronous language so the response is always sent before it gets the data from the Database. This is the test code i wrote when i go to localhost:8080 i get nothing if i refresh i get the entity. Like i said i know why, my problem is that i dont know how to make the server wait with the response until the database answers. i would need like an event or something but i dont know how should i implement it...

```
var http = require('http');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";
var requrl= "localhost:2442"
var testResult = "";



http.createServer(function(requrl,res){      
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/"; 
        MongoClient.connect(url,  { useNewUrlParser: true },function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("mydb");   
            dbo.collection("UserInformations").find({name:"a"},{projection: {_id:0}}).toArray(function(errorinfind,result){
            if(errorinfind)throw errorinfind;  
            db.close();
            testResult = result[0].name;
    }); 
});
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(testResult.toString());
    res.end();   
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: You need to perform the response.write inside the callback from the database query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `async/await`. like below:

```
http.createServer(async function(requrl,res){      
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/"; 
        var db = await MongoClient.connect(url,  { useNewUrlParser: true })       
        var dbo = db.db("mydb");   
        var resualt = (await dbo.collection("UserInformations").find({name:"a"},{projection: {_id:0}})).toArray();  
        db.close();
        testResult = result[0].name;


        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write(testResult.toString());
        res.end();   
        }).listen(8080);
```

also if you want to handle error, you can surround it with `try/catch`